# Is xmlns="" wildly used and is it good style?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

The attribute expression xmlns="" declares the "no namespace"-namespace.

For example:

```
...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/xhtml">
   <table><!--table of hotels-->
      ...
      <td>
         <description xmlns="">
            <name>Las Vegas</name>
            <city>Phoenix, Arizona</city> 
         </description>
      </td>
      ...
   </table>
</html>
```

In this example I just use it to annotate some data with elements that do not belong to any namespace.

Which makes sense to me as I don't have to find or create an appropriate namespace. Maybe sometimes you don't want to work out a schema if you won't reuse it and there's only few data to annotate with it anyway.

It would also make sense if the document above was just the first sketch before the schema design and xmlns="" elements are just used to comment on the data for future changes.

What's the common practice? Isn't it almost ever used?

Comment: Don't you use <!-- --> to comment on the data rather xmlns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarifying: Your document is `xhtml` document, and has set that as its default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/xhtml`) What the `xmlns=""` attribute does is to say that this default no longer applies, and that the element it appears on and its children are not to be understood as `xhtml` but as raw xml with no default namespace.

Yes, this syntax is widely used wherever it is necessary to cancel a default namespace (though arguably it'd be slightly better form to not set the default namespace in the first place and use prefixes on your names to bind them to namespaces).

As to whether you should be using "no namespace" in the first place: That's up to you. Namespaces are recommended for any nontrivial document type because they make it possible at some point in the future to intermix elements from that document type with elements from another document type and make sense out of the combination. Basically, if you don't use namespaces then there's a risk that your use of `<name>` for a hotel will get entangled with someone else's use of `<name>` for a human or a variable or gods-know-what.

Without namespaces, you'd have to seriously consider always writing something like  `<TRAVEL_AGENT_DATA_HOTEL_name>` to avoid that hazard. Being able to just write `<hotel:name>`, and bind the `hotel:` prefix to the namespace for travel-agent documents really is a huge improvement.

XML Namespaces were created because they were *needed*. You will use them, because you will need to use them.

Comment: thanks. the sense of XML namespaces is to distinguish the elements with same name but from different schemas. so with using xmlns="" too often, there is a threat that one can't distuingish them anymore e.g. if selecting and formatting them with CSS. But one more question: You said, that it could be slightly better to not use the default namespace in the first place. Why do you think that way?

Comment: Not necessarily just schemas. Schemas define document structure in terms of namespaces, but namespaces can  be useful independent of schemas. Schemas define document structure (higher-level syntax); namespaces define semantic identity.

Comment: Re avoiding setting a default namespace: Admittedly that's a matter of opinion, so feel free to disagree. But I've seen a few too many cases where implicit/default namespaces confused folks not used to looking for them, and/or folks who didn't understand that the default namespace doesn't get applied to attributes, and/or folks who had trouble understanding the relationship between default namespace scope and XPath/XSLT/XQuery processing. Making the binding explicit isn't that much more typing and prevents those misunderstandings. In the end, though, it's a matter of knowing your audience.

Comment: that's a very good point, i mean with the misunderstandings. haven't thought about it this way.

Comment: i have to read something about how conformance to a schema has something to do with namespaces. i'm a bit confused about that now